# How to install symfony on PHP 5.2.8 with no phar support (Composer dependency)?

Tags: php, symfony, installation, phar

I have been attempting to install symfony on my website however I have had little success as it depends on composer.

To install:

```
php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/installer'));"
```

When I attempted the install (all install options appear to require phar support) I got this output:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
Warning: Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in Command line code(1) : eval()'d code on line 378
#!/usr/bin/env php
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The phar extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-phar

Your PHP (5.2.8) is too old, you must upgrade to PHP 5.3.2 or higher.
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I do not have privileges to install a different version of php as I am using a paid webhost that is somewhat restrictive. What are my options?

Comment: The error message says it all "**Your PHP (5.2.8) is too old, you must upgrade to PHP 5.3.2 or higher.**"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Symfony 2 doesn't support php < 5.3.2  http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/requirements.html

If you cannot upgrade your php version then find another web host or use a different framework.

Comment: Look at AWS elastic beanstalk, they have a free tier and their PHP AMI is set up and ready to go for Symfony.

Comment: I'm not sure how somebody used my account to post this question, But I hope they saw the answer. I have never programmed in PHP and never posted this question. Thanks